# How can I disable cmd+tab in mac app using electron

Tags: reactjs, electron

I am trying to capture `cmd+tab` for mac and `meta+tab` for windows using `globalShorcuts` in my react desktop app. But I am not able to capture that. I can capture other combinations but I want this proccess switching to disable.

```
 globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Y', () => {
    console.log("CommandOrControl+Y is pressed: Shortcut Disabled");
    // Do stuff when Y and either Command/Control is pressed.
  })

  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Tab', () => {
    console.log("Meta+TAB is pressed: Shortcut Disabled");
    // Do stuff when Y and either Command/Control is pressed.
  })
```